# How to run JUnit tests with lsp-mode and dap-mode, without build tools like maven

Tags: lsp-mode, java, dap

I have a Guix profile in which I installed for a beginner's java class a java environment as minimal as possible: `openjdk` 17, `java-junit` (which is JUnit 4), `emacs-lsp-java`, and `emacs-dap-mode`. I installed `jdtls` from Emacs with `lsp-install-server`.

My file hierarchy looks like the following (mostly single-file exercises, I didn't see the point of creating a whole eclipse/maven project structure for each of them):

```
exercices
├── A1
│   └── Main.java
├── A2
│   └── Main.java
└── D3
    ├── hamscrest.jar -> /gnu/store/…/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
    ├── junit.jar -> /gnu/store/…/junit-4.12.jar
    ├── Main.java
    └── MainTest.java
```

When I open a `Main.java` and LSP asks for the project root, I select the folder of each exercise: A1, or A2, etc. Correspondingly, the java files do not contain a `package` line.

I then run each program with `dap-debug` using the default `Java Run Configuration` template. I'm not sure if `:classPaths nil` in the template means "the current folder" or "the LSP project root", but in this case they are the same. I can also compile and run the programs from the command line by going to the A1, A2, etc directory and running `javac Main.java && java Main`.

Now comes the problematic part: JUnit. From the command line (in directory D3), I can run the tests by including the JUnit and Hamscrest `.jar`s in the classpath, as well as the current directory:

```bash
javac -cp junit.jar Main.java MainTest.java
java -cp .:junit.jar:hamscrest.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MainTest
```

I linked the `.jar`s into D3 for convenience, so `-cp ".:./*"` is actually enough. But now, I have no idea how to get this to work in Emacs.

### Strategy 1

In LSP-mode, there are flymake errors saying `The import org.junit cannot be resolved`, `Test cannot be resolved to a type`, etc, so the language server is not aware that JUnit is installed. [Some reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/f6mfo8/comment/fi5zuhc/) hinted that "You need either a pom or a gradle file to instruct the LSP backend of your dependencies". I tried to write a `pom.xml`, and it takes effect when restarting the language server, but I get the LSP error `Main.java is not on the classpath of project D3`:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>exercices</groupId>
  <artifactId>exercices</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${project.basedir}</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</testSourceDirectory>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I took `${project.basedir}` from the [super POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#the-super-pom), but also tried to replace it by `.` or leave it empty, without difference.

I also tried to move `Main.java` into `D3/src/main/java/` and `MainTest.java` into `D3/src/test/java/` and keep out the `<build>` section in `D3/pom.xml`. In this case, flymake stops complaining about both JUnit and the classpath, but it seems that `jdtls` still doesn't know how to find JUnit: if I run `lsp-java-build-project`, `*lsp-log*` shows `Error occured while building workspace. Details: message: The import org.junit cannot be resolved`. I changed the scope because I thought JUnit might be needed at compile time too, but it makes no difference.

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>exercices</groupId>
  <artifactId>exercices</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

### Strategy 2

Probably for the same reason, DAP seems also not aware of JUnit, because the command `dap-java-run-test-method` gives the error:

```
lsp-workspace-command-execute: ‘workspace/executeCommand’ with ‘vscode.java.resolveClasspath’ failed.
(error "Unable to make private java.lang.StackTraceElement() accessible: module java.base does not \"opens java.lang\" to unnamed module @32ef26cc")
```

So I figured that since I can run the tests from the command line, I should be able to run them with `dap-debug` by changing the `:classPaths` line in the template. There is a old open [dap-mode github issue](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode/issues/165) mentioning that it should be formatted as an elisp vector.

I registered a new debug template, identical to `Java Run Configuration` except for its name and the `:classPaths` line. But I can't even find the syntax to reproduce the equivalent of the command line `-cp .`

`:classPaths ["."]` or the full path `:classPaths ["/home/.../D3"]` lead to the java error `Error: Could not find or load main class Main Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main`.

With for example `:classPaths "."`, the LSP server hangs and complains that `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at path $.classPaths`.

#### Summary

In the end, my questions would be:

- Does `lsp-java` assume a specific project structure when it needs to find external jar like the JUnit one?
- More of a java question than an Emacs one, but since `lsp-java` seems to rely on it to find dependencies, how does one write in a `pom.xml` that everything (sources, tests and dependencies) is directly in the current folder?
- How to set `:classPaths` in `dap-mode` debug templates, since `:classPaths ["."]` doesn't work where `-cp .` does?
- And the bottom-line question: what is supposed to be the correct way to use JUnit with `dap-mode`?